# Open with %APP% Always option not remembering

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, browser, chrome-for-android, barcode

I have a intranet webpage that has a button that launches a barcode scanner app, basically by calling the app through a link to the company's webiste:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success" href="http://zxing.appspot.com/scan?ret=http%3A%2F%2Fwebin1%2Fembroidery_scheduling%2Fjobs%2Fmobile%2F%7BCODE%7D&SCAN_FORMATS=CODE_39">Scan Sales Order</a>
```

When one clicks on this link a modal pops up with 'Open with Barcode Scanner' and the Just Once or Always buttons.

If I click 'Always' it never remembers. Anytime we click the button to scan, it always asks. How do I override this, or just force it to use the default app without prompting me?

Comment: Can you check with Settings -> Apps -> Barcode Scanner -> Defaults, and see if it is set to Always ask?